# MS SQL : How To Find Employee Names and Salaries Up To 10% Higher Than Minimum Salary?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have employees with names and salaries. How can I get the names and salaries of the employees, who have salaries up to 10% higher than the total minimum salary existing?

Answer (score 2):

Get the minimum salary value using a sub-query and select up-to 10% of it by multiplying 1.1(10%) to the minimum value.

**Query**

```
select [name], [salary]
from [employees]
where [salary] <= (select min([salary]) from [employees]) * 1.1;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906316/ms-sql-how-to-find-employee-names-and-salaries-up-to-10-higher-than-minimum-sa)**

Comment: You can use a subquery. No need to break this into multiple queries and use a variable. Where possible, write as few queries as possible so that the optimizer has the most latitude for deciding what order to do things in, whether it can perform the query by scanning the table only once, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries to get salaries higher by max 10%

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp e
WHERE salary * 1.1 >= (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM emp) 
  AND salary > (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM emp)
```